# Selenium not able to create login account on target.com

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try to create an account on target.com using selenium web driver, it's showing me this error "Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again." Whereas if I try to create an account in the same browser in a different tab, account get created, how do I create an account using selenium webdriver ?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")

options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/priya/Desktop/project 14/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.target.com/')

account = driver.find_element_by_id('account')
account.click()

time.sleep(1)
create = driver.find_element_by_id('accountNav-createAccount')
create.click()

time.sleep(4)
username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys('abcdef@example.com')

fname = driver.find_element_by_id('firstname')
fname.send_keys('John')

lname = driver.find_element_by_id('lastname')
lname.send_keys('Kenny')

password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys('Icecram12345')

submit = driver.find_element_by_id('createAccount')
submit.click()
driver.close().
```

link to error: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ksIv.png

Comment: Aren't you using the arguments `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` unnecessarily?

Comment: Even if I removed them, still I'm not able to create the account ! Do you have any solution to my problem that how can I create account with selenium web driver on target.com ?

Comment: Update the question with your updated code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've added code with error(in form of image) I'm getting while creating an account on target.com, please help !

Comment: It's possible that the website is detecting you are using automation and has security which disables your login.